# Mapping C++ memory ordering to Java

Tags: java, c++, memory-fences

I'm translating a small C++ snippet to java, and I'm not 100% confident around memory orderings/fences. Is this correct:

C++:

```
std::atomic<size_t> seq;
...
seq.store(1,std::memory_order_release);
...
seq.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
```

How I think it should translate to Java:

```
unsafe.putLong(addr,1);
unsafe.storeFence();

unsafe.getLong(addr);
unsafe.loadFence();
```

Is this along the right lines? (and yes there is a reason for using unsafe vs just using an AtomicLong)

Comment: Its just a guess, but I'd assume that you have to put the load fence before the getLong call.

Comment: my understanding (which may be wrong) is that loadFence will flush all reordered/pending loads sat in reorder buffer, so I'm not sure how this would help before a load operation. In my head a storeFence immediately prior to a load would seem to make sense but this isn't how the C++ was written

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is the other way round. See my answer, for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The correct ordering ist as follows:

```
unsafe.storeFence(); // this fence has to come before the store!
unsafe.putLong(addr,1);

unsafe.getLong(addr);
unsafe.loadFence();
```

The purpose of the c++ code is usually to ensure, that all stores, which have happened before `seq.store(1,std::memory_order_release)` in one thread are visible to all loads after `seq.load(std::memory_order_acquire);` in another thread, as soon as the store of 1 to `seq` itself becomes visible.

In order to transfer this to Java, you have to ensure, that no loads are reordered before `unsafe.getLong(addr);` and no stores are reordered after `unsafe.putLong(addr,1);`
If you put the `storeFence` behind the store, you don't get any guarantees about how that store is reordered compared to any other store.

If your c++ code has a different purpose, the answer might vary but for that you'd have to show an example code that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You sure on this? Lets say I previously had other stores into the same memory address that might get reordered. I only care that my load sees the "1" value, and not any of the previous stores, so why do I need to storeFence before I perform the "important" store?

Comment: @overclockwise: I'm pretty sure, unless your atomics are used in a very strange manner. Btw: the loads and stores are performed in different threads right (otherwise you wouldn't need atomics)? Maybe you should show more of your program - otherwise, there is always some guesswork about their purpose involved.

Comment: @overcockwise: I don't know about java's unsafe.put and get, but at least in C++, you would not see any reordered write accesses to the same memory location (in the same thread) even with relaxed memory ordering and it also would not reorder a load before a store to the same address (in the same thread).